# Syntax Highlighting VS Addins

Tags: visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-addins

What tools are out there that compete with this product?

[CodeKana](http://www.codekana.com/)

I know ReSharper has improved syntax highlighting. Is it comparable to this?

Comment: Note that CodeKana is now Free! so it is not really competition anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) and ReSharper do way mode than just syntax highlighting, but if that's what you're looking for, go for it they are both excellent tools.

Answer (score 2):

[VisualAssistX](http://www.wholetomato.com/) competes too. Supports VC6+, as well as C# and VB.NET too.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does Resharper provide syntax highlighting, it is imho the best refactoring tool for Visual Studio. Period.

It also has built in capabilities for running unit tests in the IDE.

Just a great tool overall.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Resharper doesn't help if you are using C++.